# A free simple module is isomorphic to the base ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, modules

If $M$ is a simple $R$-module and $M$ is free, does this imply that $M\cong R$?

My thinking is that $M$ being free implies that it has a basis, but if $x_1,x_2$ are distinct basis elements, then $0\subsetneqq Rx_2\subsetneqq M$, contradicting that $M$ is simple, so $M=Rx_1\cong R$. Is my logic sound?

Comment: Right. If $M$ is free, then $M \cong R^n$ for some $n$. If $n > 1$, then there is a nontrivial submodule isomorphic to $R$.

Comment: The existence of a free and simple module is also a strong restriction on $R$, since it doesn't have ideals. For instance if $R$ is commutative, then $R$ is a field.